# Tikzpicture position in itemize item

Tags: tikz-pgf, itemize

I'm trying to add a Venn diagram to my math homework. I figured out how to make the diagram but my problem is that the diagram is not under the `itemize` item it should be.

Here's my simplified LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\section{Task 1}
\begin{itemize}
\item[a)]
    Here's the first solution.
\item[b)]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) ellipse (4cm and 2cm) node [left = 2cm] {Thing 1};
        \draw (1cm, 0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm) node {Thing 2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

And here's the output of the LaTeX.

[image: Example output]

Why is the `b)` under the diagram? How can I position the diagram so that the `b)` is at the "start" of the diagram?

Comment: Where is "start of diagram"? in line with its top? Or in line with its center?

Comment: I would like to have it in line with its top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set diagram baseline accordingly. In your case at top of image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\section{Task 1}

\begin{itemize}
\item[a)]
    Here's the first solution.
\item[b)]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)] % <---
        \draw (0,0) ellipse (4cm and 2cm) node [left = 2cm] {Thing 1};
        \draw (1cm, 0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm) node {Thing 2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what is the desired output, maybe replacing `north` with `center` looks better. But this is a matter of taste. @Zarko's answer satisfies the requirements in the question and comments.